# Sharing model using service across controllers

Tags: angularjs

Student developer well over my head here, in relation both to Angular and more advanced JavaScript

I'm attempting to enhance a basic Angular app and need to share a model between controllers (so I can select an item (JSON object in array) in a list to show more data from the same object).

The service:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('App')
    .factory('companiesService', ['$http', 'ngAuthSettings', companiesService]); 


    function companiesService($http, ngAuthSettings) {

        var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;

        var Companies = function() {
                this.records = [];
                this.loading = false;
                this.params = {};
                this.params.filter = this.filter;
                this.params.offset = 0;
                this.params.max = 10;
        };

        Companies.prototype = {
            loadData : function() {
                if (this.loading || this.error || this.end) return;
                this.loading = true;

                $http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : serviceBase + 'company.php',
                    data : $.param(this.params), 
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                }).then(function(response) {

                    for (var i = 0, len = response.data.records.length; i < len; i++) {
                        this.records.push(response.data.records[i]);
                    }
                    this.error = response.data.error; 
                    this.message = response.data.message;
                    this.params.offset = parseInt(response.data.offset) + this.params.max;
                    this.end = len < this.params.max; 
                    this.loading = false;
                }.bind(this));
            },
            getCompany : function(id) {
                var recs = this.records;
                if (recs) {
                    for (var i = 0, len = recs.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (recs[i].id == id) {
                            return recs[i];
                        } else {
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        return Companies;
    }
})();
```

Controller (for list view) -- This works fine

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
    .module('App')
    .controller('companyController', ['$scope', 'companiesService', companyController]);

    function companyController($scope, companiesService) {
        $scope.companies = new companiesService();
    }

})();
```

How can a second controller get access to the same data, i.e. the records property of the returned 'Companies' - or more specifically, how do I call the getCompany function in the service on those records within this second controller?

Comment: It looks to me like you are creating a specific instance of the Companies class. If there are multiple concurrent users and you use a service to create multiple instances of the class by using a service. Isn't it possible that you have multiple users (or even the same user under different controllers) operating under the assumption they are working on the same object with the same inheritance when in fact they are separate objects and this could cause problems for you later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a factory, you are creating a new instance of a `Companies` object when you use the `new` keyword within your controller. If you need another controller to access this newly created company, you have a few options, but I believe the best one would be to create a service that creates a Companies object with which both your controllers can gain access to via injection. For example:

```
.service('MyCompanies', function(companiesService){
    var state = {
        companies: new companiesService()
    };
    return {
        getState: function(){ return state; }
    };
});
```

Then you can inject `MyCompanies` into both of your controllers and access the same companies instance:

```
$scope.state = MyCompanies.getState();
// now $scope.state.companies will be the same for any controller that calls the line above.
```

---

While they both can achieve the same things, I believe you should think of factories as components that create things, and services as components that hold some state that other components can interact with.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I not understand your code.For work with this you create a single as:

```
function CompaniesService($http, ngAuthSettings) {
    .
    .
    .

    var companyCache = {};

    return {
            getCompany : function(id, callback) {
            var existInCache = companyCache[id];
            if(existInCache)
                callback(companyCache[id]);
            else{    
                $http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : serviceBase + 'company.php',
                    data : $.param(this.params), 
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                }).then(function(response) {
                    companyCache[id] = response.data;
                    callback(companyCache[id]);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

In the controller pass as:

```
angular.module('App').controller('Controller1', ['$scope', 'CompaniesService']);
angular.module('App').controller('Controller2', ['$scope', 'CompaniesService']);
angular.module('App').controller('Controller3', ['$scope', 'CompaniesService']);

function Controller1($scope, CompaniesService) {
    $scope.companies = CompaniesService.getCompany(function(data){
        $scope.companies = data;
    });
}

function Controller2($scope, CompaniesService) {
    $scope.companies = CompaniesService.getCompany(function(data){
        $scope.companies = data;
    });
}

function Controller3($scope, CompaniesService) {
    $scope.companies = CompaniesService.getCompany(function(data){
        $scope.companies = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: `companyCache[id] = response.data;` not `response`

Comment: Right, i fix. Thank you!